# Upper bound on a set of functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, functions, exponential-function

Consider a finite set of functions $\{f_1(x),f_2(x),...f_n(x)\}$ where  $f_i: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}_+, \forall i$. Suppose there exist $a_i\ge0$ and $b_i > 0$ such that
\begin{align}
f_i(x) \le e^{a_i - b_i x}, \qquad \forall i, \forall x\ge0.
\end{align}
Let us define the following three scalars:
\begin{align}
a:=\max_i\{a_i\} \qquad T > \max_i\{  \frac{a_i}{b_i} \} \qquad b:=\min_i\{ b_i - \frac{a_i}{T} \}.
\end{align}
Prove that
\begin{align}
f_i(x) \le e^{ \frac{a}{2} - bx  } , \qquad \forall i, \forall x \ge0.
\end{align}

Comment: My try: It is easy to get $f_i(x) \le e^{a-bx}$. This is because $0<b \le b_i$ and also $a \ge a_i$. I do not know where the $\frac{a}{2}$ comes from.

Answer (score 1):

This is false. Let $i = 1$, $a_1 = b_1 = 1$, and let:
$$
f_1(x) = e^{a_1 - b_1x} = e^{1-x}
$$
Then:
$$
a = a_1 \\
T = \frac{a_1}{b_1} \\
b = b_1 - \frac{a_1}{\frac{a_1}{b_1}} = 0
$$
So the inequality asserts that:
$$
f_1(x) = e^{1-x} \leq e^{\frac{1}{2}} \; \forall i, \, \forall x \geq 0
$$
However, this is not true, as $f_1(0) = e > e^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am really sorry, there was a typo in the question. It should be $T > \max_i\{  \frac{a_i}{b_i} \}$ rather than $T:= \max_i\{  \frac{a_i}{b_i} \}$.